# Find element - span containing texts

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Somewhere on a page there exists this element:

№ 81776925

For me this number (that is 81776925) is crucial.

[image]

My xpath:

```
"//span[contains (text(), ‘№ 81776925’ )]"
```

Not found.

How can I find the element by that very number?

Comment: Can you show real URL link ? I have a good solution

Comment: @Gilles Quenot , this is a private area on the site. Unfortunately it is hardly possible. But I can provide any extra information of necessary.

Comment: Provide the code block as HTML you want to retrieve by editing your post

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles - this is off-topic. Voting to close as needing [mcve] for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`№` and `81776925` are in different lines hence the xpath:

```
"//span[contains (text(), ‘№ 81776925’ )]"
```

can't locate the element.

You can use:

```
"//span[contains(., '№') and contains(., '81776925')]"
```